# Is it possible to use the Visual Studio 2012 Shader Designer with Silverlight projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, shader, silverlight-5.0

I'm looking for a nice designer for making shader effects for Silverlight, and I saw that Visual Studio 2012 has a new Shader Designer. However, I am unable to create a Directed Graph Shader item to my project as instructed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315733.aspx).

Is this because Silverlight isn't supported or am I missing something else?